# Lipschitz continuity and gradient of a real-valued function on a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

The gradient of a function $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous with parameter $L > 0$ iff
$$\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\|^* \le L\|x-y\| \quad \forall x,y\in E.$$

I have two questions:

1. Why is the gradient in the dual space?
2. Since the dual norm of $\ell_p$ is $\ell_q$ with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and the dual norm of $\ell_1$ is $\ell_\infty$, we have: 
   \begin{align}
   \|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\|_\infty &\le L\|x-y\|_1 \\
   \|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\|_{\frac{p}{p-1}} &\le L\|x-y\|_p \quad \forall p>1.
   \end{align}
   Is this correct?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gradient of a function is a linear functional that gives an approximation to the function:
$$
f(x+h) = f(x) + \color{blue}{\nabla f(x) h} + o(\|h\|), \quad \|h\|\to0
$$
(I use Fréchet gradient definition here.) In scalar case, $\nabla f(x) h$ is just $f'(x)h$, multiplication of two numbers. In $\mathbb R^n$, it is $\nabla f(x) \cdot h$, inner product. But when $h$ is in a Banach space $E$, a linear functional is an element of the dual space; thus, $\nabla f(x) $ can only be understood as an element of $E^*$.

One could say that $\nabla f(x)$ was *always* in the dual space, we just did not notice it before because the dual of $\mathbb R^n$ is habitually identified with $\mathbb R^n$ itself.

The formulas you wrote for the special case $E=\ell_p$ are correct.

---

As an exercise, you may want to find $\nabla f(x)$ explicitly for $f(x)=\|x\|$ and check that the stated inequality indeed holds.

For example, if $p=1$, then the gradient of the norm at $x=(x_i)$ is $(\operatorname{sign}x_i)$, assuming none of $x_i$ are zero. (Otherwise, the norm is not differentiable at $x$.) As you can see, this gradient is a vector of $\pm 1$, so it makes sense that it  lives in $\ell_\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted and +1 :D